# Was/were in "Orion and Crew Dragon data was/were added."

Tags: word-choice

I wanted to confirm which of the options would be correct here. My brain can find reasoning for both.

Reason for "were":

1. The sentence could be rephrased as "Orion data and Crew Dragon data were added.", in which I'd use were since there are two names ("Orion data" and "Crew Dragon data").

Reason for "was":

1. I may be wrong in this, but I think that "Orion and Crew Dragon" can work as a modifier to "data". In this case I'd use "was", since the subject would be "data".

I think both of them might be valid choices, but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: 'Data', I notice, is now being treated as plural. It used to be regarded as a singular. I cannot quantify or tabulate this. I have just noticed it in documentaries and news items.

Comment: It was added as a single blob of data.

Comment: You'd say *salt and fresh water were added,* so it should be *were.* (Unless *Orion and Crew Dragon data* is a single thing, like *clean and clear water.*)

Comment: @PeterShor They are two different spacecrafts, so the first analogy is the correct one. Could you write that as an answer so that I can accept it? PS: Totally unrelated to the original question but just a curiosity: I take that "salt and fresh water" refers to salt water and fresh water. If one would want to say that "salt" and "fresh water" were added, how would you do it? Possibly change the order into "fresh water and salt"?

Comment: *Fresh water and salt* is a good suggestion. If you want to keep the same order, you could say *Salt was added, along with fresh water*.

Comment: @NigelJ "Data" is plural,  it is the plural of "datum". If indeed the use of it as a singular word is going out of fashion that is merely a return to its technically correct usage. Not that long ago people were arguing _against_ the use of "data" as a singular noun and getting quite hot under the collar about it.

Comment: And while we are on that subject, the plural of spacecraft is spacecraft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Data* is a confusing word, because sometimes it's treated as a plural, and sometimes as a mass noun. See the discussion in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data). If you're treating it as a plural, you clearly should use *were*. But even if you're treating it a mass noun, you should use *were*.
You'd say that

> salt and fresh water *were* added,

so it should be *were*.

On the other hand, if *Orion and Crew Dragon* data was a single thing, like

> clean and clear water,

then it would be *was*.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

> Orion data and Crew Dragon data *were* added.

This is because at least two data were added: one *datum* from Orion crew and one datum from Crew Dragon.

If you were using adding a single point (a *datum*), you would say:

> The Orion temperature datum *was* updated for last Monday.

Here is the [APA Style guide](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/07/data-is-or-data-are.html#:%7E:text=This%20is%20certainly%20the%20case,followed%20by%20a%20plural%20verb.) (6th ed) with a blog that backs up this distinction:

> To help clear up any confusion regarding the proper use of these
> terms, I list examples of datum and data being used correctly below:
>
> > Each datum matches the location of an object to a coordinate on the map.
>
> > Although we have compiled the results, these data are the focus of another report and are not described here.

On the other hand, *datum* seems to be dying out (in American English, at least). If it were only one piece of data being discussed, it's not uncommon to hear:

> Crew Dragon data *was* added.

Comment: *Data* was plural in **Latin**. So was [*agenda*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/agenda). But Latin isn't English. Nobody says *the agenda for this meeting are ...*

Comment: @PeterShor . Please note that I cited a contemporary AP Style blog, so there is at least one person who can contradict your "nobody" assertion. Also note that I acknowledged in the last paragraph that "*datum* seems to be dying out." When I was an editor, we maintained the datum/data subject-verb agreement because it was indicated in our style guide, CMoS. And I think your argument for Latin origins may fall apart if you think Marshall McLuhan was wrong to say "The medium is the message."  It grates on my ears to hear speakers and writers confuse one medium with many media.